# Can I get Cyrillic with google translate's Japanese IME more efficiently?

Tags: discussion, ime

If I am entering Japanese at https://translate.google.com/ , and type in "roshia" (or "kiriru"), as well as some options for Japanese words, I get each letter of the Russian Cyrillic alphabet.

Currently, you have to scroll through the full menu to get the letter you want. Apart from switching to the Russian keyboard, is there a more efficient way of getting the letter I want?

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use Russian input?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky curiosity, mainly.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Translate (PC ver), if you switch the language to translate to Russian, there will be an icon on the bottom-left of the entry box. Click on that and a soft keyboard of Russian will appear below the entry box. You can then click on the letter(s) you want, then copy/paste from the entry box.

Though this method technically does not use the Japanese IME.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a question about Japanese IME built by Google, i.e. Mozc

- PgUp/Down keys turn previous/next page of candidates (Same as MS-IME)
- You can set suggest words function on

Then, while you type "Rosia" system suggests ロシア, press TAB to select, depends how many time you type "rosia" and it becomes quicker.